# how to select samples that cover all my clustered samples

Tags: matlab, sampling

I extracted features from video samples and then each feature is normalized (grouped/quantized/clustered) to values from 1-4 or from 1-3.
I need to do my experiment in few samples that cover all features quantized values.

Example:

sample          f1       f2    f3,

s1                   1         2     1,

s2                   2         2     1,

s3                   2         1     2,

s4                   1         1     1,

s5                   3         1     1,

here I can choose s1, s3, and s5 to represent my samples. I can skip s2 because I have f1=2 in s3 and f2=2 in s1 and f3=1 in s1 and s5.

thanks

Comment: Unclear. Could you edit question and elaborate a bit ?

Comment: I edited it. tell me if it is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. What tool/programming language do you use ? What do you call a "feature" in a video sample ? As such, I'd be surprised if anybody can answer. Is this more an "algorithmic" question ?

Comment: I am using matlab. The feature might be the std of the frames' Intensity.

Comment: Then add the `matlab` tag to attract matlab guys over here. And add your comment to the question.